# Pythagorean triplets

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Respected Mathematicians,

For Pythagorean triplets $(a,b,c)$, if $c$ is odd then any one of  $a$ and $b$ is odd. Here $(a, b, c)$ is a Pythagorean triplet with $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

Now, I will consider $c = b + \Omega$. The reason for considering $c = b + \Omega$ is, $c$ is a hypotenuse side of right triangle and it is obviously larger than the other side $b$.

Now, 
$$a^2 + b^2 = (b + \Omega)^2 = b^2 + 2b \Omega +  \Omega ^2\qquad\qquad(1)$$ which is same as 
$$b = [a^2 -  \Omega ^2] \div 2\Omega.$$ 
Which implies that $\Omega$ divides $a^2$ for $a^2- \Omega ^2) \gt 0$ or $(a - \Omega) (a + \Omega) \gt 0$, which implies that 
$$a \gt \Omega\qquad\qquad(2).$$

Now, I will consider $a = 2^m$; then $\Omega$ is also even. Otherwise, if $a = 2^m + 1$ then obviously $\Omega$ is odd.

Now, I will consider both $a$ and $\Omega$ is an even numbers such that, $a = 2^m$ and $\Omega = 2^r$ for some $m$ and $r$. By (2), we have $m \gt r$ and by (1), we have
$$(2^m)^2 = 2^r (2b + 2^r)$$
or 
$$b = \frac{2^r}{2}((4^m \div 4^r) - 1))\qquad\qquad(3)$$

As I said earlier, $a$ and $\Omega$ is an even, then $b$ should be an odd number. i.e., $r  = 1$

Therefore, the required triplets for even numbers in powers of $2$ are 
$(2^m, (4^m \div 4) - 1, (4^m \div 4 ) + 1))$

Now my question is, how one can generalize the same for following?

Case 1: if we take odd numbers for powers of some prime

Case 2: if we take even numbers with prime powers.

Thanking you,

Comment: When I am generalizing, I am always committed for some sort of errors. I am not able to do for other cases. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear to me what you are going for; for one thing, not every even number is a power of $2$. For another, even if $a$ is a power of $2$, you have no warrant to assert that $\Omega$ will necessarily be a power of $2$ as well; at least, no warrant that you have given. Of course, you may *assume* that's the case, but then you are dealing with a rather restrictive subset of pythagorean triples.

For another, it is false that if $a$ is even then $b$ is necessarily odd, though it is true for *primitive* pythagorean triples (ones where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are pairwise relatively prime). But you never make that assumption.

And finally, a complete description of primitive pythagorean triples is well known. You can deduce your formula from them rather easily.

Explicitly, suppose that $(a,b,c)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple, and let us assume that $a$ is even; we have
$$(c+b)(c-b) = c^2-b^2 = a^2;$$
since $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime, and $a$ is even, then $b$ and $c$ are both odd, so $c+b$ and $c-b$ are both even. Any common divisor of $c+b$ and $c-b$ will divide $(c-b)+(c+b) = 2c$, and also $(c+b)-(c-b) = 2b$; since $\gcd(2c,2b) = 2\gcd(b,c) = 2$, the gcd of $c-b$ and $c+b$ is $2$. Dividing through by $4$ (which we can do since $a$ is even, so $a^2$ is a multiple of $4$, we get
$$\left(\frac{c+b}{2}\right)\left(\frac{c-b}{2}\right) = \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2.$$
Since $\frac{c+b}{2}$ and $\frac{c-b}{2}$ are relatively prime, and their product is a square, they are each a square. So we can write $\frac{c+b}{2} = s^2$, $\frac{c-b}{2}=r^2$, $\frac{a}{2} = rs$, with $r$ and $s$ positive, $s\gt r$, relatively prime, *and* of opposite parity (since $c$ is odd).

This gives 
$$\begin{align*}
c &= \frac{c+b}{2} + \frac{c-b}{2} = s^2+r^2.\\
b &= \frac{c+b}{2} - \frac{c-b}{2} = s^2 - r^2.\\
a &= 2rs.
\end{align*}$$
In your case, you want $a=2^m$; since $s$ and $r$ are of opposite parity, one must be equal to $1$; since $s\gt r\gt 0$, we will have $r=1$, $s=2^{m-1}$, and this gives 
$$(a,b,c) = (2^m, 4^{m-1}-1, 4^{m-1}+1),$$
which was your result.

Note, however, that there are other (non-primitive) Pythagorean triples that have $a$ a power of $2$: namely,
$$(2^{m+k}, 2^{2m+k-2}-2^k, 2^{2m+k-2}+2^k)$$
is a Pythagorean triple for all $k\geq 0$.

If $a$ is odd, then just exchange the roles of $a$ and $b$ above.

Comment: Nice answer , it was much informative.

Comment: No doubt! your explanation gave me some other idea to develop constructive proof(s). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First $A\ne 2^n,n\in\mathbb{N}$ because
$A=2n+1.\quad$ What you are seeing is
$2|((A-\Omega )^2$ where $\Omega=c-b=(2n-1)^2$ and $b=4n, n\in\mathbb{N}.$ All primitive triples are generated by a formula I developed in $2009$:

\begin{align*}
  A=(2n-1)^2+                     & 2(2n-1)k      \\ 
  B=  \qquad\quad\quad   & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2\\ 
  C=(2n-1)^2+                    & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2\\
\end{align*}
and it is easy to set that
$ C=(b+\Omega)\implies \Omega = (2n-1)^2$
e.g.

$$(3,4,5)\rightarrow \Omega=1^2,
\quad \dfrac{3^2-1^2}{2\cdot1}=4\\
(15,8,17)\rightarrow \Omega=3^2,\quad \dfrac{15^2-9^2}{2\cdot 9}=8\\
(35,12,37)\rightarrow \Omega=5^2,
\quad \dfrac{35^2-25^2}{2\cdot 25}=12\\$$

You can explore these combinations more in this sample generated by the formula above.
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5   \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61 \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125\\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 \\ \hline
Set_{6} &43,24,145 &165,52,173 &187,84,205 &209,120,241 &231,160,281 \\ \hline
\end{array}